# Passing argument 4 of 'obj_setProperty' from incompatible pointer type

Tags: objective-c, xcode, delegates

I am getting the above compiler error in XCode, and I cannot work out what's going on.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

// #import "HeaderPanelViewController.h"
#import "HTTPClientCommunicator.h"
#import "WebSocket.h"

@class HeaderPanelViewController;

@protocol ServerDateTimeUpdating
-(void)serverDateTimeHasBeenUpdatedWithDate:(NSString *) dateString andTime:(NSString *) timeString;
@end

@interface SmartWardPTAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, WebSocketDelegate> {

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) id<ServerDateTimeUpdating> *serverDateTimeDelegate;
....
@end
```

Then in this line

```
@synthesize serverDateTimeDelegate;
```

in ApplicationDelegate.m I am getting the error "Passing argument 4 of 'obj_setProperty' from incompatible pointer type". I did a bit of research and found that 'retain' only works on class types, which is fair enough. If I actually remove the 'retain' from the line

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) id<ServerDateTimeUpdating> *serverDateTimeDelegate;
```

it does compile without complaints. However, I think, that's the wrong thing to do. Surely my 'id' *is* a class type and surely it *should* be retained in the setter. BTW, here is the declaration of my HeaderPanelViewController which implements the aforementioned protocol:

```
 @interface HeaderPanelViewController : UIViewController<ServerDateTimeUpdating> {

 }

...
@end
```

Also, if I actually *do* remove the retain I get a problem later down the track when I actually call the setter to register my HeaderPanelViewController as the delegate:

```
// Register this instance as the delegate for ServerDateTimeUpdating
// Retrieve the ApplicationDelegate...
ApplicationDelegate *applicationDelegate = (ApplicationDelegate *) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
// ...and register this instance
applicationDelegate.serverDateTimeDelegate = self;
```

The last line causes the XCode error message "Passing argument 1 of 'setServerDateTimeDelegate' from incompatible pointer type".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is the property declaration:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) id<ServerDateTimeUpdating> *serverDateTimeDelegate;
```

If you command-double click "id", you'll see it defined as:

```
typedef struct objc_object {
  Class isa;
} *id;
```

In other words, `id` is *already* an object reference.  Therefore, the `*` right before `serverDateTimeDelegate` is unnecessary and wrong.  Having it there means a pointer to an object reference, when you really just want an object reference.

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is here:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) id<ServerDateTimeUpdating> *serverDateTimeDelegate;
```

`id` is already a pointer type, so you declaring `serverDateTimeDelegate` as a pointer  (`*`) effectively makes the property a pointer to a pointer.

Get rid of the `*` and everything should work fine.